# array.push not working typescript/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Environment: Angular 6:
I have a blank array defined in the `class` and `interface` as below: and

```
   export class Student {
    fullName: string;
    age: number;
    classType: string;
}
export class MyClass {
    public resultData: Array<Student> = [];
    processedData = {
        studentData: [
            {
                name: 'Nayan',
                type: 'toddler',
                classType: 'secondary'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rajesh',
                type: 'infant',
                classType: 'primary'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rithik',
                type: 'toddler',
                classType: 'secondary'
            },
            {
                name: 'Rob',
                type: 'toddler',
                classType: 'primary'
            },
            {
                name: 'Daneirl',
                type: 'toddler',
                classType: 'secondary'
            }

        ]
    }
    resultData1 =[
        {name:'nayan', age:8, classType:'primary'},
        {name:'Daniel', age:15, classType:'scondary'},
        {name:'Rithik', age:12, classType:'secondary'}
    ]

    someEventClickedFormView() {
        this.processedData.studentData.forEach((data, index) => {
            switch (data.classType) {
                case 'primary': {
                    this.processName(data, 'fullName', index);
                    this.processAge(data,'age',index);
                    break;
                }
                case 'secondary': {
                    this.processName(data, 'fullName', index);
                    this.processAge(data,'age',index);
                    break;
                }
            }

        })
    }
    public processName(data: any, fieldName: string, index: number) {
        this.resultData.push({ fieldName: data.fullName })

        // here I am getting error
        //         Argument of type '{ fieldName: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Student'.
        //   Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fieldName' does not exist in type 'Student'.ts(2345)
    }
    public  processAge(data:any,fieldName:string,index:number) {
        this.resultData.push({ fieldName: this.someTransformationToAge(data.age)})

    }
}
```

at button click event which is here someEventClickedFormView being called and pushes the data into resultData coming from mock data.

However, I am getting errors as below: you can see above code section push method.

```
Argument of type '{ fieldName: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Student'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'fieldName' does not exist in type 'Student'.ts(2345)
```

basically, I want `resultData` as below

```
  resultData =[
        {name:'nayan', age:8, classType:'primary'},
        {name:'Daniel', age:15, classType:'scondary'},
        {name:'Rithik', age:12, classType:'secondary'}
    ]
```

Comment: If you want `resultData` to be a list of students, why are you pushing `{ fieldName: data.fullName }` which has nothing in common with a student?

Comment: I did not get you, fieldName is 'fullName; which is property of Student interface itself

Comment: No, `fieldName` is `fieldName`. If [it was dynamic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/how-to-use-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal), it would have been `{ [fieldName]: data.fullName }` And even then, that's ***not*** a student object. A student, as defined in your interface, has three mandatory properties: `fullName`, `age`, and `classType`. Having just one is still not a valid student.

Comment: ok can, you mean putting index like this.this.resultData.push({ [fieldName]: data.fullName })

Comment: other two properties would be added at later stage in processing, wont it work ? is there index plays a role here, do you have any working example

Comment: I mean that *even if you do that*, you would not have a valid student object, because it requires three properties and you're only providing one

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248287/discussion-between-angularguy-and-vlaz).

Comment: Do index plays a role here? for example at same index I can add another property ? what is other alternative if you have

Answer (score 0):

I think this simple logic should suffice. Create object of student class , set the members as per logic. I do not see difference between 2 cases of switch statement. hence have put simple attribute assignment

```
 someEventClickedFormView() {
         
        this.processedData.studentData.forEach((data, index) => {
            Student s = new Student();
            s.name = data.fullName;
            s.classType = data.classType;
            s.age = this.someTransformationToAge(data.age);

            this.resultData.push(s);
            // switch (data.classType) {
            //     case 'primary': {
            //         s.name = data.fullName;
            //         s.classType = data.classType;
            //         s.age = this.someTransformationToAge(data.age);
            //         this.processName(data, 'fullName', index);
            //         this.processAge(data,'age',index);
            //         break;
            //     }
            //     case 'secondary': {
            //         this.processName(data, 'fullName', index);
            //         this.processAge(data,'age',index);
            //         break;
            //     }
            // }

        })
    }
```

Comment: I added processAge as well, that is same as processName, based on type the age will be determined.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the 3 functions someEventClickedFormView() ,processName() and procesAge() with the below single function .
Here are 2 solutions for getting your desired result.

**Solution 1 :**

```
someEventClickedFormView() {
    this.processedData.studentData.forEach((data, index) => {
        let studentRecord = {};
        studentRecord['name'] = data.fullName;
        studentRecord['age'] = data.age;
        studentRecord['classType'] = data.classType;
        this.resultData.push(studentRecord);
    })
}
```

**Solution 2:**
If you want to add any extra dynamic key to the object along with the existing key values, try this solution where the dynamic field **dynamicNameField** is set with the value passed as parameter(the below solution is passing fullName as a dynamic key) to function **processDynamicValue()** from below code .

```
someEventClickedFormView() {
    this.processedData.studentData.forEach((data, index) => {
        let studentRecord = {};
        studentRecord['name'] = data.fullName;
        studentRecord['age'] = this.someTransformationToAge(data.age);
        studentRecord['classType'] = data.classType;
        
        //use the below 1 line and the function processDynamicValue() to add any dynamic name to key of the studentRecord object to be pushed to this.resultData array.
        studentRecord=this.processDynamicValue(studentRecord,'dynamicNameField',data.fullName);
        this.resultData.push(studentRecord);
    })
}
processDynamicValue(studentRecord,fieldName,valueToSetToDynamicField){
   studentRecord[fieldName] = valueToSetToDynamicField;
   return studentRecord;
}
```